# Remove halo around image before segmentation (preprocessing)

Tags: python, image, opencv, image-processing, image-segmentation

I'm trying to perform image segmentation using [Morphological Snakes](https://github.com/pmneila/morphsnakes), however the input images contain something like a halo that it is messing with the output. [Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XFWbQ.png) you can see an example image and its corresponding segmentation should look like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rqlws.png). As it can be seen in the first image the object of interest is the one in the center but around it there is, what I call, a gray halo and since the difference among the pixels is not much I haven't found a way to perform the segmentation.

I've tried preprocessing methods such as morphological operations and gaussian filter, however I didn't obtain the expected results. I've also tryed to segmentate the image using adaptative threshold and otsu, but didn't work either because, as I said before, the difference among the pixels is not much (that's why I moved to morphological snakes that work better but not enough for my case).

I want to know if there's any preprocessing method that could help in my case, maybe I haven't found the correct combination of them. I need to remove or clean the halo, or to highlight the the object in the center.

Thanks in advance to any who could help me.

Comment: can you help to draw whats the thing you want? i saw 2 results. but got no idea whats your expected results. please rephrase your question in a clear manner

Comment: Always best to provide separate images if you want people to be able to experiment with your data.

Comment: I modified my question according to your suggestions, hope now its clearer. Thank you

Comment: In the example image, it looks like the halo is mostly (1) low-frequency, (2) and the frequency is restricted to a relatively tight bandwidth. In other words, the 'halo' is blah and gray, but also somewhat consistent. You should try filtering based on the pixel-to-pixel differences. Try applying a Hessian matrix, and blurring the result with a Gaussian filter.

Comment: @bey I've tried applying what you suggested using the heassian matrix filter implemented here. However it only increased the visibility of the "halo". Here you can see the output https://imgur.com/7KuQEiJ
Am I missing something related to your suggestion?

Comment: @CVV I think you’re close. Before applying the hessian, you should first apply a binary mask. Then, apply the hessian only to that content, and you won’t get that ring at the edge. Then, Gaussian blur. Then, you could try applying a convex hull around pixels over a particular threshold. The stuff within the hull is probably what you’re after.